# Legal questions - On topic or not?

Tags: discussion, site-topic

[Can I register myself as CEO for my freelancing company besides being a regular full time employee in a Corporate](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/710/can-i-register-myself-as-ceo-for-my-freelancing-company-besides-being-a-regular) was asked this morning, but seems to deal more with being a startup company, or with legal advice. What would the community like to see done with this type of question? Can we reword it to be a better fit for the site? Can we include this in the scope?

Comment: Good call on editing to make it fit! I just posted a follow-up question for the op to see if we can get more details. :)

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://meta.freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/14/should-law-specific-questions-be-encouraged ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a problem with that type of question - other than it pretty-much repeats a previous question on the same topic.

As I commented on [Should law-specific questions be encouraged?](https://freelancing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14/should-law-specific-questions-be-encouraged)

> "Without a doubt, Legal Questions are going to be a fundamental part
>   of this site - because so much of freelancing involves legal matters."